# Арифметика двух чисел и знака

Tags: java, rmi, арифметика

Подскажите как можно решить мою проблему.
Нужно передать два числа и знак(+ или - или *)  на сервер ( по технологии `RMI`), где он складывает эти два числа или вычитает или умножает, в зависимости от знака.
Как это можно реализовать?

Answer (score 1):

Передавать знак операции вряд ли хорошая идея. Лучше иметь на сервере отдельные методы для складывания, умножения и тд.

Сервер можно реализовать в виде REST сервиса (это не единственный способ).

Далее реализовать клиент, который будет вызывать методы сервиса, как обычные методы (в чем и заключается суть технологии `RMI`)

В сети много информации по этому поводу, рекомендую почитать, вот несколько ссылок:

[одна из реализаций спецификации rest сервисов](https://jersey.github.io/)

[хабр](https://habr.com/post/115718/)

[еще](https://crunchify.com/how-to-build-restful-service-with-java-using-jax-rs-and-jersey/)

Это далеко не все, вам предстоит ознакомиться с кучей материала, прежде чем решать подобную задачу.